# when to use authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

when to use 
windows authentication, form authentication, passport authentication, none?
I don't find on internet any relevant matter on it, although all say how to use these authentication.
But no one says which one is superior and when to use one.
Please elaborate a little on it.
Also i want to know benefit of one over another, and what is that authentication i did by now by creating table with user id and password and match the user id and password with the data table. If that can be done easily what is the need of these authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the project and what you want to achieve. If you were developing an Intranet for a company obviously only to be accessed from internal computers then windows authentication would be the choice.

If you want people to register and wish to access as much information as possible then use forms authentication to get the data you require and store it alongside membership.

If you want people to come and go from your site with ease with as little steps as possible for registration, then use Passport.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But form authentication stores user id, password in cookies, woun't it make the cookies heavy if more number of users are registered?

Comment: Passwords aren't stored in cookies. Also cookies have no relation to the number of users registered since they are stored client side. Feel free to take a look at this link which describes how it works :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows authentication is generally for companies where people do something locally and server checks if the computer that is trying to do something is valid.
Example: Company that accepts some requests and people working there do something with them.

Forms authentication is for whole web where you want people to access the content regardless from PC/other device? they are using.
Example: Website like this.

Comment: Where the windows authentication stores the user id, password.

Comment: Oh, see here, there are several different methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Windows Authentication is generally used for Active Directory-enabled networks, such as Intranet sites etc. where the user's Windows credentials double as a login to the web app.

Forms Authentication allows you to use the .NET Membership/Role/Login features and control a more in-depth user database.

I've never come across a good reason to use Passport Authentication, but it's a proprietry MS single-signon style authentication method.